# Making splash screen animated in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, app-store

In cocos2d there is always a splash screen by default. How to replace it (or just to delete that one and make other way) with something animated , for example? Is it good idea at all? How it affects the moderation?

Comment: Just read this document. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html. You should provide launch image. If you have any animations then just use first frame of that animation as Splash Screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how we've handled this in our game in cocos2d-x:

1. Set a blank Orange LaunchImage in Xcode.
2. In the AppController as soon as the EAGLView is setup we change it's backgroundColor to the same Orange as our LaunchImage because it was showing a black screen for a split second before showing our animated splash scene/layer.

   ```
   __glView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:GC_BG_COLOR_RED green:GC_BG_COLOR_GREEN blue:GC_BG_COLOR_BLUE alpha:1];
   ```
3. Created a scene/layer before the menu that is shown for 3-4 seconds, on which we show our brand's logo animation.
4. On completion of the animation we reset the backgroundColor back to the default black.

Answer (score 1):

your splash screen image replace the "Default.png" in project resource.

Comment: I know that I can change default image to my own. Static image looks pretty boring - that's why I' d like found, whether I can set a kind of animation instead .png image?